# AngularJS - ngRoute not loaded?

Tags: angularjs

Application code looks like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
      controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/succes', {
      templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
      controller: 'SuccessController'
    }).
    othervise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

and I will run that it throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:4957
    at p (angular.js:410)
    at g (angular.js:4917)
    at gb (angular.js:4839)
    at c (angular.js:1949)
    at Uc (angular.js:1970)
    at xe (angular.js:1855)
    at angular.js:33826
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3468)
```

but I have `angular-route` loaded

```
<script src="js/lib/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Any clue why it indicates that ngRoute is not loaded?

Comment: What does the full error message tell you regarding which module isn't available? Note if you use development version of angular will get more verbose error output

Comment: did you check your app name?

Comment: @AvrilLavigne Is the same - `myApp`

Comment: @charlietfl Error message updated and I'm using stable version 1.6.5

Comment: Change `othervise` to `otherwise`! :)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Yeah, I have done that and solved my silly issue.  Are there any IDE editors which can pick AngularJS directives so I can avoid typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here, you should use **otherwise** instead of **`othervise`** . Since the config is not right, it tries to load the module and hence that also fails.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
      controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/succes', {
      templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
      controller: 'SuccessController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: It can have multiple answers, i provided with the explanation

Comment: Anyway are there any IDE editors which can pick AngularJS directives so I can avoid typos?

Answer (score 2):

i can see othervise instead of otherwise

Comment: Good eye! To make the answer better, it would be helpful to point out where that error is.

Comment: @praveenuics Just WOW! Such of typo cause issue. Anyway are there any IDE editors which can pick AngularJS directives?